# Apex add id to button with image

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to style a button that is an image in oracle apex. All I need to do is put some padding at the bottom of the button but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. My thought was to somehow declare a unique id for the button and use CSS but I can't find where to declare a unique ID or even a class id for the button. I do not want to use the generic  tag to style it because it is a unique button. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure that the button template includes the `#BUTTON_ATTRIBUTES#` substitution string. e.g.

```
<button value="#LABEL#" onclick="#LINK#" class="button-gray" type="button"
  #BUTTON_ATTRIBUTES#>
  <span>#LABEL#</span>
</button>
```

Then change the button itself and set the Button Attributes property to something like:

```
id="MY_BUTTON"
```

Now you can reference MY_BUTTON in CSS and Javascript.